# Can not get remote access to RabbitMq server

Tags: python, linux, rabbitmq, ip, pika

I can't get remote access to the RabbitMq server. When I am doing this at one machine and connect to localhost:15672 it works, but when I try from a remote machine it's not.

I have already created a user with all permissions and check that 5672 port on computer works (just tried to connect to him from a remote computer). Also, I tried to connect to 15672 port, but no result.

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username= 'username', password='password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='188.19.100.226',
                                   port=5672,
                                   virtual_host= '/',
                                   credentials=credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                  routing_key='hello',
                  body=hello)
print ("Sent!")
connection.close()
```

I expect to see Sent!, but instead of I get:

```
ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.io_services_utils:Socket failed to connect: <socket.socket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.100.2', 44752)>; error=111 (Connection refused)
ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:TCP Connection attempt failed: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'); dest=(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('188.19.100.226', 5672))
ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnector - reporting failure: AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused')
ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQP connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'); first exception - None.
ERROR:pika.adapters.utils.connection_workflow:AMQPConnectionWorkflow - reporting failure: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'); first exception - None
ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - AMQPConnectorSocketConnectError: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'); first exception - None
ERROR:pika.adapters.blocking_connection:Error in _create_connection().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/trrp2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/trrp2/send.py", line 52, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=parameters)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/trrp2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/trrp2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

Comment: You should not share a public IP address. Also, please read this and do the tests - https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure rabbitmq to listen to other interfaces than local host.
To accept connections from all interfaces, listen to 0.0.0.0

https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#interfaces

Comment: Hm, I do not have file rabbitmq.conf, there is only two files: rabbitmq-env.conf and enabled-plugins

Comment: You need to add one. I think rabbitmq has defaults to get you started, but they don't open ports I. An unsecure way. Unless you do it explicitly.

Comment: But port is open. I tried to connect to it directly, through a remote terminal and it was successful

Comment: I'm not refering to the port. I'm refering to the listening interface. The default Listening interface for rabbitmq is localhost, which means that it will not accept connections from anywhere except localhost. 
If you set the interfaces configuration to 
listeners.tcp.1 = :::5672
Then you tell rabbitmq to listen to all interfaces, and you should be able to connect from another machine

Comment: all interfaces are open by default